# Tracking changes made to tables by another source

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a program that centralizes a large number of work orders from multiple different sources. Each user that uses this program can track specific work orders and see their status. These work orders are often modified and I would like to be able to track whether or not they have been changed since the last time that the Work Orders were checked

I am looking to update a program to be able to track specific changes to rows defined by a specific Work Order Identifier

Because each user has a local backend database on their computer which contains the tracked work orders ID numbers. The option I am looking at right now is to store each individual work order locally and compare it against the work order tables each time the user views their tracked work orders. However because of the fact that there are several tables (one for each facility), each facility has a large number of work orders, and each user has dozens of work orders this would slow down the program considerably and I would prefer to not do this.

The other option I looked into was audit tracking, however because the change is made by the a backend SQL insertion and not through my program this is not an option.

I would prefer if there was an option that does not need to create several new tables, AND query the numerous databases and entries on each time the WO has been viewed.

Comment: No matter what method you use you are going to have caveats. Since you have multiple clients with multiple back end files, you are going to have to track the changes per client. Then based off of some interval update a single table containing log information at a centralized location. The most optimal solution would be having a centralized Back end file used by all users, then doing the auditing with changes from there.

Comment: you could try built-in `replication` functionality, or write some in-house code due to Getz's recommendations. But sorry, it seems it has been removed from 2007 and older versions

Comment: "Because of some system limitations" needs more detail, maybe they can be removed. Using serveral tables for each facility is a strong indicator for poor database nomalization (should be one table with a facility field added).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher that was a typo sorry and it's due to the fact that each facility has lots of different components and work order classifications (I did not create the tables)

Comment: Poor database design leads to poor data! Mistakes here will always bite you. The reason for not shared backend?

Comment: I am unsure as the tables were created before I arrived at the company, each one has the same formatting. It might be due to the lack of communication between the facilities, or the fact that they are on separate sites. I would fix it as I've heard that a lot from stack overflow but, I don't have edit access to the tables